# Is there any way to know if the user is using the django web application from different devices?

Tags: django, web, request, device

I want to build a web application where the user can only browse or use the site from one device that he used while first signing up to the site. Let's say I used device **A** (It can be anything like android, desktop etc) to register. So If I want to browse the mentioned site using a different device the server will not allow me to browse that site. 
More precisely, suppose **A** is an Android device. So If I use another Android device **B** to browse the site it won't allow. I need **A** to browse the site.

Using **Django - Python Framework**.

Comment: there are various methods to achieve that. For example store permanent cookies on device on registration and require those cookies present, or similar approaches

Comment: add db entry on registration with device identifier (eg userAgent , etc.) and so on. Is another approach